# XAML button question?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have this for a hyperlinkbutton:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Home" 
  NavigateUri="/Home" 
  TargetName="ContentFrame" 
  Content="Home" 
  Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonStyle1}">
```

Trying to accomplish the same using `<Button>`, any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple.  All you need to do is change the template to make it look the way you want.

[Here's a blog post which goes into the details for changing the template for a Button.](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html)  All you need to do is change the template to something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
  <TextBlock Foreground="Blue">
      <ContentPresenter/>
  </TextBlock>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Of course, you might be able to sneak out the template for a HyperlinkButton using Expression (it might also be lurking somewhere on MSDN) and reuse it...

---

With a button, I'd do the folowing (using codebehind blech):

```
<button Content="Navigate to my page!" Click="Button_Click" />
```

and in the codebehind:

```
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the page to navigate to
        var page = new MyPage();

        // Navigate to the page, using the NavigationService
        // this assumes that the event handler is inside of a
        // NavigationWindow
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for the navigation uses.  To put a panel in a target frame.  I am sure it is pretty simple, just not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user Well, its not exactly that simple.  Are you using navigation controls (such as NavigationWindow) or are you muscling it via codebehind/ViewModel?

Comment: @ Will,

I am using navigation controls